# How do I version a route in Ember properly?

Tags: ember.js

I have an application where I would like to namespace a specific route. But I'm seeing that Ember renders the ancestor route (which is similarly named).

**Details**

Ember 1.12.0

**Routes**

```
this.resource('campaign', { path: ':campaign_id' }, function() {
  // some more routes
});

this.resource('campaign_v2', { path: 'v2/:campaign_id' }, function() {
  // new routes
});
```

**Link in campaign template**

```
{{link-to "Check out V2!" "campaign_v2" classNames="btn btn-primary"}}
```

**Test**

- Expect: When visiting campaign.index and I click on "Check out V2!", I expect to be taken to campaign_v2.index
- Result: I am taken to campaign_v2.index but campaign also renders

Here is the result in Ember Inspector:

[image]

However, if I reload the route, I get:

[image]

Comment: Have you done any processing in `renderTemplate` hook? Can you create a short version of your case in http://ember-twiddle.com/ or  http://emberjs.jsbin.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `resource` helper and instead use the `route` helper. Also, you might consider using a route namespace (instead of the _v2 suffix).

**Routes**

```
this.route('campaign', { path: ':campaign_id' }, function() {
  // more routes
});

this.route('v2', function() {
  this.route('campaign', { path: ':campaign_id' }, function() {
});
```

You can then refer to the v1 and v2 route via: `campaign` and `v2.campaign` respectively.